# Find where an xml element occurs in relation to other elements using PHP

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

I am using PHP's simpleXml to display a musicxml file as a musical score on the screen. Everything is working well unless there is a clef change somewhere in the score. Here is an excerpt of the xml file showing a clef change in measure 27:

```
<measure number="27">
  <note>
    </note>
  <note>
    </note>
  <attributes>
    <clef number="2">
      <sign>F</sign>
      <line>4</line>
      </clef>
    </attributes>
  <note>
    </note>
  <note>
    </note>
  <note>
    </note>
  </measure>
```

I am going through the notes in each measure via **foreach ($measure->note as $note)**. I can detect a clef change in a measure via **if(isset($measure->attributes->clef))** but this doesn't tell me *where* the clef change occurs (after the second note of the measure and before the last three notes, in this example.)

I looked into simpleXmlIterator, but it doesn't seem to handle an excerpt out of an simpleXml object ($measure in this case.) I tried:

```
$sxi = new SimpleXMLIterator($measure);
```

This gave me the following warning:

> Warning: 
>   SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 29: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found

When I `var_dump($measure)` I see that it places the clef change at the end of the notes array, but assigns it a number that could be used to determine its proper place in the sequence of notes:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (4) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["width"]=>
    string(6) "468.94"
  }
  ["note"]=>
  array(25) {
    ...
    [20]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (5) {
      ["rest"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#49 (0) {
      }
      ["duration"]=>
      string(1) "4"
    }
    [21]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (7) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["default-x"]=>
        string(6) "293.75"
        ["default-y"]=>
        string(7) "-255.00"
      }
      ["pitch"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#49 (2) {
        ["step"]=>
        string(1) "D"
        ["octave"]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
      ["duration"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  ["attributes"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#44 (1) {
    ["clef"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#49 (3) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["number"]=>
        string(1) "2"
      }
      ["sign"]=>
      string(1) "G"
      ["line"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Object #44 (the clef change) should come between the two notes [actually, a rest and a note] that are objects #43 and #45. So, if I could figure out a way to access those "object numbers" my problem could be solved. Does anyone know how to do this, or a better way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I realized that the return value of simpleXml() is an object (not an XML string.) So I can't feed a portion of it into simpleXmlIterator() and expect anything but errors.

Instead, I ended up treating $measure properly: as an object, and iterated through it as follows:

```
if(isset($measure->attributes->clef) && $measureNbr > 0) {
    // There is a clef change in this measure!
    $clefNbr = $measure->attributes->clef->attributes()->number;
    $durationBeforeClefChg=0;
    foreach($measure as $property => $value) {
        // Count the unchorded durations before the clef change.
            if(is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                foreach($value as $p2 => $v2) {
                    if(trim($p2) == 'duration' 
                        && $property == 'note' 
                        && ((!property_exists($value,'staff')) 
                            || trim($value->staff) == $clefNbr) 
                        && !property_exists($value,'chord')) {
                            $durationBeforeClefChg+= intval(trim($v2)); 
                    }
                    if(trim($p2) == 'clef' && $property == 'attributes') {
                        $newClef = trim($v2->sign);
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider an [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) solution. This special-purpose XML transformation language can run the `preceding-sibling::*` and `following-sibling::*` XPath methods to retrieve count of `<notes>` elements before and after `<attributes>` in a new, separate XML file.

PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class. Below demonstrates with sample XML rendering an output of specific information. With this approach, no nested `foreach` looping with `if` logic is needed.

**Input XML** *(different measure numbers with attributes in various positions and one with no clef)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<score-partwise version="1.0">
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">
      <part-name>Voice</part-name>
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="26">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
    </measure>
    <measure number="27">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
    </measure>
    <measure number="28">
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
    </measure>
    <measure number="29">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
          <test>XSLT is cool!</test>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl to be parsed in PHP below either by file or string)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="measure">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <notes_before_clef><xsl:copy-of select="count(attributes[clef!='']/preceding-sibling::note)"/></notes_before_clef>
         <notes_after_clef><xsl:copy-of select="count(attributes[clef!='']/following-sibling::note)"/></notes_after_clef>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(enable php-xsl extension in .ini file)*

```
// LOAD XML AND XSLT
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('Input.xml');         // OR $xml->loadXML($xmlstring);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');   // OR $xsl->loadXML($xslstring);

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);    

// TRANSFORM SOURCE TO NEW TREE
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

// SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output XML** *(parse this file for end use needs)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<score-partwise version="1.0">
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">
      <part-name>Voice</part-name>
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="26">
      <notes_before_clef>5</notes_before_clef>
      <notes_after_clef>0</notes_after_clef>
    </measure>
    <measure number="27">
      <notes_before_clef>2</notes_before_clef>
      <notes_after_clef>3</notes_after_clef>
    </measure>
    <measure number="28">
      <notes_before_clef>1</notes_before_clef>
      <notes_after_clef>4</notes_after_clef>
    </measure>
    <measure number="29">
      <notes_before_clef>0</notes_before_clef>
      <notes_after_clef>0</notes_after_clef>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>
```

Comment: Thanks, Parfait! This opens up new possibilities of pre-massaging the xml to something more convenient to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, run XPath directly with PHP's [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) using `preceding-sibling::*` and `following-sibling::*`. Below creates a multidimensional array, *$clefs*, indexed by measure number with two inner arrays for *before_notes* and *after_notes*:

Sample XML

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(
'<score-partwise version="1.0">
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">
      <part-name>Voice</part-name>
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="26">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
    </measure>
    <measure number="27">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
    </measure>
    <measure number="28">
      <note/>
      <attributes>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
    </measure>
    <measure number="29">
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <note/>
      <attributes>
          <test>XSLT is cool!</test>
      </attributes>
      <note/>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>');
```

Parsing Code

```
$clefs = [];    

foreach($xml->xpath('//measure') as $item) { 

   $measure_num = (integer)$item->xpath('@number')[0];

   $clefs['before_notes'][$measure_num] = count($item->xpath("attributes[clef!='']/preceding-sibling::note"));
   $clefs['after_notes'][$measure_num] = count($item->xpath("attributes[clef!='']/following-sibling::note"));

}

echo var_dump($clefs);
// array(2) { 
//   ["before_notes"]=> array(4) { 
//        [26]=> int(5) [27]=> int(2) [28]=> int(1) [29]=> int(0) 
//   }
//   ["after_notes"]=> array(4) { 
//        [26]=> int(0) [27]=> int(3) [28]=> int(4) [29]=> int(0) 
//   } 
// }
```